# How do you code a beat gesture in ELAN?

Tags: cognitive-linguistics

In gesture studies, a beat is described as a gesture which punctuates discourse and signals important parts of speech. I am working on gesture and I have to differentiate beats from other types of gestures in ELAN. What are the different phases of a beat gesture? What is the significant phase of a beat gesture?